# What needs to be covered in a java record

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage, record, java-17

I was doing some junit testing in my codebase and found that Intellij is marking all my simple Record classes as 0% covered

I have a simple record that looks like this :

```
public record ProcessRequestDTO(String path) {
    // NOTHING HERE
}
```

My question is, what do Intellij coverage expect me to cover here ? Constructor ? Getters/Setters ? if the latters are true, why is non-record classes annotated with @Getter, @Setter, @AllArgsConstrusctor are not even detected as to be covered ? (see next code)

I can't use jacoco right now so I'm expecting an answer for the default Intellij coverage tool.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Other{
    private File file;
}
// This class is not even added to the coverage pool
```

Edit, as this subject is not clear, I add this images which represents classes marked as 'nothing to cover' and classes marked as "potential for coverage here"
[image]

Comment: *"It is a culture question, not an issue."* - Therefore ... opinion-based.  *"My question is, what do Intellij coverage expect me to cover here?"* - Try it and see.

Comment: No ... Intellij is a software tool.  It doesn't have "culture".   Perhaps the problem is that you don't know what the word means.   But anyway, the answer to the (real) question you are asking is to try it yourself.  Write a `record`, and some code that uses it in a test and see what coverage is reported by Intellij.  Then >you< decide whether >you< think the coverage reporting behavior is what >you< need.

Comment: Asking us whether we think Intellij's behavior is useful IS an opinion question ... and won't achieve anything.  Asking us what Intellij "expects" ... you can answer for yourself, by trying it out for yourself.  It will >tell< you what it expects.   And anyway, coverage stats should not determine how you write your tests.  The tests should be designed to identify potential bugs.  Coverage stats are a means to an end, not an end in themselves.

Comment: The question is not about whether it is good or bad to test or to coverage. The question is about why Intellij determines some classes needs to be  covered and some not. I do not want to test that or coverage that, I just want to know why is there "0% classes, 0% lines covered" (implying there are things to cover) on some classes and nothing on others (implying there is nothing to cover here) I will add pictures but I'm sure mighty moderators will tell me its forbidden. And yes "culture" may not have the same signification as in French "culture" word, sorry for that.

Comment: @StephenC How IntelliJ determines percent of code coverage and why it's showing 0% coverage is a valid, answerable question about how to use a programming tool IMO. I'd be interested to see the answer to this too, actually - I've truthfully never thought about the specifics of this kind of question.

Comment: A general rule about unit tests is that the accessor methods of data objects don’t need to be unit tested.  (I could swear a list of recommended practices used to be on junit.org, but the closest thing I can find is [this](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/best-practices-to-write-junit-test.html#axzz8DIWalSLD).)  Records are data objects by definition, so I would say that IntelliJ should not be considering any default methods of records as needing code coverage.

Comment: Hello @VGR, thank you , that is what I thought. Empty record only defining fields should not be marked as "potential to cover" because there is nothing to cover. This is not an opinion, if there is nothing to test or cover, then Intellij should not mark the class . I will open an issue on jetbrains

Comment: It is an opinion.  SOME people think that accessor methods DO need to be tested and will expend developer effort make it happen.  (I disagree with them ... but they ARE entitled to that opinion.)

Comment: Most coverage tools work by mapping bytecode instructions back to line numbers. A quick test revealed that common compilers do indeed provide `LineNumberTable` attributes, mapping `record` constructor and all methods to the same line number, the one containing the record declaration. Since that makes only one line to cover, I suppose, just calling the constructor would be enough to consider 100% covered—at least JaCoCo behaves that way. Just check whether IntelliJ does the same. The coverage calculation algorithms are not very sophisticated. Neither do these tools understand test worthiness.

Comment: What is strange in this calculation of LineNumberTable is that record with one line is marked as potential for cover, but a class with dozens of getters/setters, constructors added wit Lombok (implying dozens of real code lines), there is no potential for cover for the tool, and the class is not marked. As if it was aware of lombok context, and decided all this lines were not worthy of covering. I can't say if bug or due to no recent update to correctly manage record in such tool.

Comment: But "strange" is an opinion, I think the subject can now be closed, without further explanation added by the jetbrains team

Comment: Looking at the image: Both DTO classes likely don't have any logic: they might be records without logic or Lombok-generated classes (impossible to say without seeing the code). The last class sounds like a class with real logic, `XmlParser`: I'm sure there's plenty of logic to meaningfully test (again, impossible to say without seeing the code). I'll leave this as a comment and not an answer, because this is all just guessing. This question is basically unanswerable

Comment: you can try switch to a jacoco runner as I think they were filtering out accessors, see https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1215 and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html#5aaefe9

Comment: As said, the `LineNumberTable` attributes matters. If Lombok doesn’t generate line numbers for the generated members, the code coverage tool will treat them as “not worth covering” because it can’t measure how much they’re covered. It may also consider “synthetic” methods as “not worth covering”, though as far as I know, this heuristic has been dropped with Java 8, because lambda expression bodies are compiled into synthetic methods but have associated source code lines. You may use `javap -v -c …` to check how the compiled code looks like.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**; When running jacoco, it seems that you need to call constructor and getters in order to get record declaration covered. I suspect IntelliJ expects the same, since both rely on bytecode instrumentation.

##### Steps to reproduce

I created a simple record:

```
public record Foo (String bar) {}
```

Then created a test case where I called both constructor and getter:

```
assertThat(new Foo("Test").test()).isEqualTo("Test");
```

Then I run tests with mvn and `jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.11`:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent test org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report
```

Then I opened the results with *Run - Show Coverage Data...* and chose generated `jacoco.exec` file. It shows the `Foo` class covered 100%.